# Conditionally select constant instead of column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select contract, vehicle and revenue values from a trips table in SQL Server without selecting the revenue for a certain contract and vehicle. For example:

```
    SELECT contract, vehicle, revenue FROM trips
```

But the revenue should show `0` where the contract is `John Doe` and at the same time the truck is 'Truck 1' because that trip's revenue needs to show somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

You need a pretty simple CASE statement to do what you're after.

```
SELECT
contract
,vehicle
,CASE WHEN contract = 'John Doe' THEN 0 ELSE revenue END AS revenue
FROM trips
```

Comment: Also to prevent problems with Case Sense and extra spaces (in begining, in ending, double spaces) condition. From: contract = 'John Doe' To: 
TRIM(LOWER(REPLACE(contract, '  ', ' '))) = 'john doe'